# Função que converte hexadecimal para binário

Tags: c#, .net, string, hexadecimal, números-binários

Existe alguma função equivalente à `bin2hex()` do PHP para C#?

Preciso converter um hexadecimal para binário. Tentei usar o `TryParse` mas não tem dado certo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem sim, as funções de conversão de tipos permitem usar a base que está precisando:

```
Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32("4F56A", 16), 2)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/TReytP). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GVylpV). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/Hexadecimal2.cs).

Documentação [`Convert.ToString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToString_System_Int32_System_Int32_) e [`Convert.ToInt32()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_System_Int32_).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, Obrigado!